# unable to access location ssd

Tags: mount, hard-drive, error-handling

I have three different drives on my PC and when trying to open one of the SSD's it gives me this error message

> Unable to access location
> Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/milly/Large:
> wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

[image: error-picture]

Comment: You've provided little specifics; we don't know what Ubuntu product & release of that product you're using, we don't know what *file-system* exists on your *sdc1*, nor how you actually attempted to `mount` it (*was it appropriate for your unstated file-system; has your system got suitable modules installed & available for that unstated file-system*), and is the drive healthy?  (ie. *you've checked that via SMART etc*?)

Comment: im on version 23  and the file system is the default and the way im attempting to mount it is im trying to open it in the files app

Comment: What is version 23??  Ubuntu's 23rd release was Ubuntu 16.10 from 2016-October, which is years past its *End of Life*.  Ubuntu's release format is *year.month* where 2023-October's release is Ubuntu 23.10 though some specialist *snap* only products do use the *year* format (*but are only released on even years, eg. Ubuntu Core 22 being the last*)

Comment: What format is sdc1? If NTFS probably a Windows issue like you left it hibernated or fast startup on which sets hibernation flag. Or NTFS corruption that can only be fixed from Windows.

Comment: im on 23.10 and idk the format i doubt its windows and it was fine until today ive been running ubuntu for a while now im not sure why its stopped working